# Error in autocorrelation function (ACF): Missing values in object

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation

I am working on a time-series data that has structure as follow:

```
str(tseries)
 Time-Series [1:479] from 1979 to 2019: 0.0258 0.0234 0.0055 0.0302 0.0305 0.0232 0.025 0.0234 0.0074 0.0089 ...
```

I am trying to conduct time-series analysis and therefore use the autocorrelation function (ACF). First it was able to return the plot when run:

```
acf(tseries)
```

Yet it gave me an error when I tried to execute differentiated and logged acf() function:

```
> acf(diff(log(tseries)))
Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object
In addition: Warning message:
In log(tseries) : NaNs produced
```

What does the missing values it refer to? Because I have made sure that the data set I am working on has no missing values at all, if that's what it means.

Answer (score 1):

As Corey answered, the problem is taking the log from negative values.
I wanted to add a comment at his answer for explaining some more on how to solve your problem, but it turns out my explanation is too long.

Adding a constant could solve your problem, but it depends on what the numbers actually are whether that makes sense/is a valid approach.
Generally, ARIMA and autocorrelation means that any values you measure are dependent on previous values. For example, if I want to predict tomorrow's temperature, I look at today's: the 2 are related.
That is what testing for autocorrelation means: looking if a values in a series are correlated with other values close by in that same series.

In some cases the effect is more multiplicative, and an increase from 1000 to 1100 is more likely than an increase from 1 to 101. If it is fully multiplicative, the increase from 1000 to 1100 is just as likely as an increase from 1 to 1.1
In these cases, taking the log makes sense, the differences in log are an indication of a percentual increase or decrease. Which means a log can't handle a switch in the sign: you can't go from 1 to -1 by multiplying or dividing by any positive number.

This can also be dependent on what your actual values mean. Anyone will understand that an increase in temperature from 1º C to 2º C is just as meaningful as an increase from 33.8º F to 35.6º F, even though the first one looks like an 100% increase, and the second just a 5% increase. That means taking the log of a temperature in Celsius or Fahrenheit is pointless, although sometimes the log of a temperature in Kelvin or Rankine makes sense.

In reality, most problems will be a mix of linear and multiplicative effects, where an increase from 1000 to 1100 will be just as likely as an increase from 1 to 2 or something similar.
So it depends on what your data represents, and you need to find some calculation for which the autocorrelation is strongest. And actually, the suggestion of adding some constant to your `a` and taking the log works well for that!

To the question of what constant to choose, you need to answer for yourself: "which increases are just as likely as others?"
In my examples, saying an increase from 1000 to 1100 is just as likely as an increase from 1 to 2, means solving the equation `(1000+c)/(1100+c)==(1+c)/(2+c)`, where `c` is the constant we're looking for. Here it turns out to be 9.09, although the auto-correlation-function is not sensitive to small differences.

And you can play a bit with it as well, or maybe try other kind of functions. The stronger the auto-correlation, the better your fit.

Comment: Does that equation you worked out to find the value of `c` apply to any other numbers?

Comment: Yes, it´s just answering the question: which 2 ratios are equally likely?

Answer (score 0):

If your time series has any negative values, log will result in `NaN`, which causes your error of missing values.

```
> a <- c(-1,2,3,4,5,6)
> acf(diff(log(a)))
Error in na.fail.default(as.ts(x)) : missing values in object
In addition: Warning message:
In log(a) : NaNs produced
```

Comment: What should I do to the negative numbers, then?

Comment: I can't appropriately answer that question because I don't know the origin of your time series. If you have negative values, then you cannot take the logarithm because it's not defined (try doing `log(-1)` in R to see the proof for yourself). If you want to make it work, you could take the absolute value and then the logarithm, but that would be changing the time series.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but I am able to plot the line chart with diff and log function <plot(diff(log(tseries)))>

Comment: When you plot you should get the error `Warning message: In log(a) : NaNs produced`. It still plots because it is plotting all the points *except* the negative value. So therefore the plot can still be shown. The solution is to either not use `log` because it doesn't work with negative values, or change the negative values/remove them so you can use `log`. For example, you could make a boolean indicating if a value was negative, then absolute value everything, then take logarithm, then negate values if they were previously negative.

Comment: I see. I saw a solution where it suggested to add a constant value just to get rid of the negative values, and then subtract it back afterward when it comes to predicting. Although, do you think the log scaling is necessary for my dataset? I read that stationary series is crucial for ARIMA model.

Comment: @Corey Levinson Negating the logarithm is entirely different from negating the input. If I understand you correctly you'd want to transform -10 to -2.3, as log(10)=2.3, right? But at the same time, log(.1) would also give -2.3

Comment: @EmilBode Wow, I've never thought of that before. You're absolutely right. I was lucky in that I've only ever done that technique where all absolute values were >= 1, but I will keep that knowledge from now on!

@MuhammadAkbarAlmuttaqin That is a solution, sure, if your only goal is to plot *something* (it's not clear if that will be worthwhile). Instead of taking logarithm, you could also have the axes at a logarithmic scale, too. The `diff` part is important though for time series if your series is monotonic